# Is it possible to get timestamp format 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS.xxxxxx.nnnnnnnnn' in java?

Tags: java

Is it possiblle to get timestamp format like `'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS.xxxxxx.nnnnnnnnn'` in java?
Here

```
xxxxxx - microseconds
nnnnnnnnn - Nanoseconds
```

Anybody can help this?

Comment: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826270/how-to-convert-hhmmss-sss-to-milliseconds)

Comment: No, you cant do that. The only thing you can do is multiply milliseconds by 10^x and convert it unaccurately into other units. You can get nanoseconds using `System.nanoTime()` , but thats strictly for performance measures, like calculating start and end time difference of an event in nanoseconds, and does not provide total nanoseconds elapsed with respect to a fixed time.