# How to get number of milliseconds from start of day

Tags: java, android, date, timer

For example, if it's 1 p.m (13:00) and I need to get the number 46800000 (13 hours from beginning o day) in milliseconds. Could anyone please help?

Comment: you mean count of milliseconds in that particular day...

Comment: Based on *title* **and** *body* of the question, Toan Le is asking for the number of milliseconds since midnight.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a Calendar to calculate it. You set the time to the hour 0 and calculate the difference:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long millis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Great answer! Should be helpful to 'em.

Comment: Refer this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826270/how-to-convert-hhmmss-sss-to-milliseconds

Comment: This answer is incorrect and doesn't answer OP's question for future readers

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Using the Joda-Time 2.5 library, it is an easy one-liner.

```
long millisOfDay = DateTime.now(  DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).getMillisOfDay();
```

Note how time zone is crucial. If omitted you implicitly rely on the JVM’s current default.