# Convert MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a format to milliseconds

Tags: android, date, google-calendar-api

I am trying to Convert date and time i am receiving in **MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a** format to milliseconds so that i can push the date as end date in google calendar. I am trying below code but i am getting error.

**Code:**

```
String myDate = "10/20/2017 8:10 AM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
long millis = date.getTime();
```

**Error:**

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10/20/2017 8:10 AM" (at offset 16)
```

Comment: Please try with "MM/dd/yyyy k:mm a"

Comment: I think the given value of your myDate is not exactly to your Date Formatter. try to change your myDate to "10/20/2017 08:10 AM" Since you're using a `hh` [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Jerrol i tried what you suggested but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Cata i tried what you said still issue is there.

Comment: The code you have posted works correctly https://i.imgur.com/S22RkVs.png . Are you getting this error when you run that exact code?

Comment: @Stephen yes i am getting that error when i run that code.

Comment: @Stephen can you please tell me whether the number i am getting is too long ?

Comment: @Ironman yea you and either my code is working. https://imgur.com/a/66aAP

Comment: @Ironman, It is not too long. A Java long is 8 bytes which is enough to store your milliseconds. Can you show your import statements?

Comment: @Stephen please find my import statements in this link https://imgur.com/a/I0Wtc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this .

```
String myDate = "10/20/2017 8:10 AM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
long millis = date.getTime();
```

**Add `Locale.ENGLISH` in your code .**

Comment: You can try again.

Comment: Still same issue i am getting.

Comment: can you please tell me whether the number i am getting is too long ?

Comment: You can try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK, i've just added `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    String myDate = "10/20/2017 8:10 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
    long millis = date.getTime();

    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(millis);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

This code prints 1508479800000 as `millis`. If you want to check it backwards try this:

```
String x = "1508479800000";

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

            long milliSeconds= Long.parseLong(x);
            System.out.println(milliSeconds);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

this will give you `10/20/2017 08:10 AM`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to do it. You just have to know 2 things.

All dates are internally represented in UTC
.getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
package se.wederbrand.milliseconds;

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {        
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        String inputString = "00:01:30.500";

        Date date = sdf.parse("1970-01-01 " + inputString);
        System.out.println("in milliseconds: " + date.getTime());        
    }
}
```

by this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/8826392/8456432

Comment: i am already using `SimpleDateFormat`. Please check my input value.